# Llamar a un método Index de un controlador desde _Layout.cshtml

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

Tengo un proyecto en [.net-core](/questions/tagged/.net-core). con `mvc` (es una práctica). Lo cree de la forma tradicional, tengo los modelos y en base a ellos los controladores. Funciona correctamente, ya que fue creado con sus asistentes y corre: puedo ver los datos de mi tabla. Pero ahora resulta que quiero trabajar con Ajax, entonces sé que debo hacer algunos cambios.

Y fue lo que hice. Ahora las preguntas son las siguientes:

Agregué a mi barra de menús en la parte superior un `link` para que me lleve directo al *Index*, y funciona perfectamente.

```
<a id="anticipo" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="ComAnticipoes" asp-action="Index">Anticipos</a>
```

para que llamar a mi link ( <a ) desde un evento jscript para ello agregue un Id. y elimine alguna parte del código quedando de esta manera.

```
<a id="anticipo" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" >Anticipos</a>
```

Luego para probar como puedo llamarlo desde una función hice lo siguiente:

```
<script>

    $("#anticipo").click(function () {
        alert("Hola mundo")
        //CargarDatos(); Para llamar a la funcion cargarDatos
    });

</script>
```

de hecho me muestra el mensaje.

Ahora, quiero hacer lo mismo, osea traer los datos, pero con Ajax, (algo que nunca he usado),
para ello hice lo siguiente, esto agregando a la función anterior lo siguiente:

```
<script>
    $("#anticipo").click(function () {
        //alert("Hola mundo")
        CargarDatos();
    });
    function CargarDatos() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "ComAnticipoes/Index",
                cache: false,
            success: function (dataHtml) {
                $("#example").html(dataHtml);
            }
        })
    }
    
</script>
```

pero esto ya no funciona, todo lo hice basado en ejemplos del internet.

Aclaraciones: todo esto que les he mostrado hasta el momento esta hecho en la vista `shared _Layout.cshtml`.

Tengo este controlador en la carpeta `controllers`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using DBfirts.Models;

namespace DBfirts.Controllers
{
    public class ComAnticipoesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ChilyBravoContext _context;

        public ComAnticipoesController(ChilyBravoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: ComAnticipoes
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.ComAnticipos.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: ComAnticipoes/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var comAnticipo = await _context.ComAnticipos
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AnticipoId == id);
            if (comAnticipo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(comAnticipo);
        }

        // GET: ComAnticipoes/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: ComAnticipoes/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("AnticipoId,EmpresaId,TipoAnticipoId,AnticipoNro,Fecha,PedCompraId,ProveedorId,MonedaId,TipoCambio,AnticipoDes,AnticipoObs,MontoAnt,MontoDes,GestionId,TipoCompId,CompNro,PlanId,EstadoId,SLastUpdateId,DtLastUpdateDt,IConcurrencyId,ConFac,SinFac,CentroCostoId,AnticipoOrden,AnticipoIdOrg")] ComAnticipo comAnticipo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(comAnticipo);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(comAnticipo);
        }

        // GET: ComAnticipoes/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var comAnticipo = await _context.ComAnticipos.FindAsync(id);
            if (comAnticipo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(comAnticipo);
        }

        // POST: ComAnticipoes/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("AnticipoId,EmpresaId,TipoAnticipoId,AnticipoNro,Fecha,PedCompraId,ProveedorId,MonedaId,TipoCambio,AnticipoDes,AnticipoObs,MontoAnt,MontoDes,GestionId,TipoCompId,CompNro,PlanId,EstadoId,SLastUpdateId,DtLastUpdateDt,IConcurrencyId,ConFac,SinFac,CentroCostoId,AnticipoOrden,AnticipoIdOrg")] ComAnticipo comAnticipo)
        {
            if (id != comAnticipo.AnticipoId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(comAnticipo);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ComAnticipoExists(comAnticipo.AnticipoId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(comAnticipo);
        }

        // GET: ComAnticipoes/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var comAnticipo = await _context.ComAnticipos
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AnticipoId == id);
            if (comAnticipo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(comAnticipo);
        }

        // POST: ComAnticipoes/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var comAnticipo = await _context.ComAnticipos.FindAsync(id);
            _context.ComAnticipos.Remove(comAnticipo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool ComAnticipoExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.ComAnticipos.Any(e => e.AnticipoId == id);
        }

    }
}
```

y de todos estos es al método *Index* que deseo llamar.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.ComAnticipos.ToListAsync());
}
```

claro que no me muestra ningún error.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Has verificado que error te sale en la consola de javascript, la mayoría del debug se hace con la consola.

Comment: También verifica que este llegando los datos al servidor, sabes en que punto del código se recibe los datos en el lado del servidor???

Comment: No llega ningún error a la consola.,pero si los datos viene cuando los llamo de la forma normal

Comment: a que te refieres de la forma normal??? bueno imprime el response de javascript por consola con: `console.log(response)` a ver que te sale...

Comment: Con normal me refiero a que hago el llamado desde la url sin hacer ningún cambio y me muestra los datos pero cuando lo hago con ajax ya no carga nada y tampoco muestra algún error.

Comment: pero el response no debe estar vacio.. debe decir algo...o no tiene sentido lo que dices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observaciones.

1. Si estás trabajando desde javascript puro y nada tiene que ver ASPnet, retira los prefijos de `asp-` puesto que generan una ruta que no necesitas.
2. Es importante que se verifique desde F12 -> Network y se seleccione "ALL" para que veas todas las peticiones, muchas veces se olvidan de ver si la URL está bien armada o no, en caso esté mal hecha, se ve un error 404.
3. En tu Ajax, mencionas `$("#example")` y el Div con id "example" estuvo inexistente, motivo por el cual, no se pudo visualizar el resultado, a pesar que la petición estuvo bien realizada.